# Laravel Sqlsrv Tried to bind parameter number 2101

Tags: php, laravel, sqlsrv

I'm changing my software database from mysql to sqlsrv, now I have this issue on simples queries, can anyone give me a hint on what to do?

My query is:

```
$foobar = Foo::with('bar')->get();
```

when I do this laravel runs a "`where` in" command on all the items om my '`bar`' table! (I currently have 50k+ items on my table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with chunk

```
$collection= collect();
$foobar = Foo::with('bar')->chunk(500, function ($rows) use ($collection) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $collection->push($row);
    }
});
```